# How to get a GKE node pool in different zone than cluster (zonal cluster)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, node-pools

I have a GKE cluster in `us-central1-c` zone and I wanted to add an L4 node pool to it.

I currently use Terraform to maintain this and setting the `location` of the node pool seems to be ignored by Terraform and it tries to find the machine type in the cluster's original zone.

> Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid machine type `g2-standard-16` in zone `us-central1-c`: googleapi: Error 404: The resource `'projects/isolate-dev-smiling-shark/zones/us-central1-c/machineTypes/g2-standard-16'` was not found, notFound., badRequest

So I figured out G2 machines are only available in `us-central1-a` and `us-central1-b`.

```
❯ gcloud compute machine-types list --zones=us-central1-a | grep g2
g2-standard-12    us-central1-a  12    48.00
g2-standard-16    us-central1-a  16    64.00
g2-standard-24    us-central1-a  24    96.00
g2-standard-32    us-central1-a  32    128.00
g2-standard-4     us-central1-a  4     16.00
g2-standard-48    us-central1-a  48    192.00
g2-standard-8     us-central1-a  8     32.00
g2-standard-96    us-central1-a  96    384.00


❯ gcloud compute machine-types list --zones=us-central1-c | grep g2


❯
```

I went into the UI and tried to create such a node pool by hand and I am not able to select the machine type.

Is it possible to have a zonal cluster in `us-central1-c` and a node pool in `us-central1-a` and how could I achieve it?

If not, what would be the recommended course of action to move the whole cluster to `us-central1-a`? (I would really prefer not having to do this).

Comment: When creating your node pool with Terraform, are you setting node location(s) using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#node_locations ?

Comment: @GariSingh I tried that and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[g2-machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) types do not exist on us-central1-c.

As stated in the regional cluster [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters#limitations)

> To run GPUs in your regional cluster, choose a region that has at least one  zone where the requested GPUs are available. You must use the --node-locations flag when creating the node pool to specify the zone or zones containing the requested GPUs.
>
> If you need to, you can change or edit a cluster's zones, which causes
> all new and existing nodes to span those zones, and add the L4 machine
> types.

Do note that [you cannot change it from zonal to regional, or regional to zonal cluster type](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-zonal-cluster).

Comment: But going from single-zonal to multi-zonal is possible, right?

Comment: Thanks, I just added node locations and it worked!